# Inherited constructor java : Call to super() must be first statement

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

Trying to do some stuff with in Java but I run in problem when doing the constructor.
My code :

Piece constructor

```
public Piece(Chessboard chessboard, Position position, Color color, String name, char symbol) {
    this.board = chessboard;
    this.position = position;
    this.color = color;
    this.name = name;
    this.symbol = symbol;
}
```

Bishop constructor (extends from Piece) :

```
    public Bishop(Chessboard board, Position position, Color color) {
        char symbole;
        if(color.equals(Color.BLACK)) 
            symbole = Symbol.BLACK_BISHOP.getCode();
        else 
            symbole = Symbol.WHITE_BISHOP.getCode();
    super(board, position, color, "Bishop", symbole);
}
```

When I'm trying to do it like this, I get an error on the super call : "super() must be first statement in constructor body".

The only fix I see would be to replace 'symbole' in the super() call by an expression which would get the correct symbol in function of `color` but I can't manage to do it?

My Symbol class is just an enum with a field `code` which represents the code of the chess piece. All pieces are stated like `COLOR_PIECE` example : `BLACK_BISHOP`

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ternary conditional operator can solve your problem :

```
public Bishop(Chessboard board, Position position, Color color) {
    super(board, position, color, "Bishop", color.equals(Color.BLACK)?Symbol.BLACK_BISHOP.getCode():Symbol.WHITE_BISHOP.getCode());
}
```

Comment: Just one sec before me my friend  :P

Comment: Wow thanks a lot, it is working, I have never used ternary operator, thought IF condition could replace it all the time :/

Answer (score 4):

The ternary operator - as shown in the answer of Eran - can solve your problem in this situation.

But sometimes you can't compute the value of a super constructor parameter in this fashion. For these cases you can use a `private static` helper function:

```
public class Bishop {
    private static char computeSymbol(Color color) {
         <complicated computation>
         return result;
    }

    public Bishop(Chessboard board, Position position, Color color) {
        super(board, position, color, "Bishop", computeSymbol(color));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Super keyword in java

The super keyword in java is a reference variable that is used to refer immediate parent class object.

Whenever you create the instance of subclass, an instance of parent class is created implicitly i.e. referred by super reference variable.

Usage of java super Keyword

1) super is used to refer immediate parent class instance variable.
2) super() is used to invoke immediate parent class constructor.

3) super is used to invoke immediate parent class method.

For example -

```
 class Example{  
  Example(){System.out.println("Example is created");}  
  }  

class Sample extends Example{  
  Sample(){  
   super();//will invoke parent class constructor  
   System.out.println("Sample is created");  
  }  
  public static void main(String args[]){  
   Sample b = new Sample(); 
   }
}
```